# Android IAP returning BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR(6) on consumePurchases?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

**Edited: A big change to reflect only what I discover that is related with the problem.**

I can't have sure if my APP is working because IAP sandbox in most of times are returning BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR for consumePurchases.

I am testing in a old device motorola milestone 1 (android 2.3.3 cyanogen) and I am integrating Unity3d with IAP. (Unity3d is opengl game engine)

The simple android native app with the same IAP is always working, for list, purchase and consume.

I have read that BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR could be a timeout.

When device is cold (not running 3d stuff for a time) appear to works little better.

Could it be caused by timeout because the slow device takes too much time to switch from unity3d and native code?

Comment: Hey, how did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ERROR is really representing a timeout, but not for network. But CPU overhead between switching contexts that take more that 20 seconds.

The problem appears to be frequent only for poor devices using very intensive App.

The solution is to optimize your code to use less resources and reduce the communications between your hungry app and iap service.

For example: Consume the purchase directly after receive a purchase response, don't create no new thread or invoke any events in the app.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I solved this with this code:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getSkuDetails = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getSkuDetailsRun();
            }
        });
        getSkuDetails.start();
    }
});
```

And in the **getSkuDetailsRun()** method I create the request... And the response code was **"0"**

I hope I could help!